# google drive API authorize issue

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I followed the tutorial on the google drive, it says that to persist the authentication/access token we have to use refresh token, so that we don't have to ask user to authenticate/authorize every time we make an API call.

**Code:**

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';


$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('client ID');
$client->setClientSecret('client secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('URL');

$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();


// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate();

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$files = $service->files->listFiles();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($files);
```

This gives me the list of files and folders, but every time I refresh the page it takes me back to google authorization page. I can save the access token in database but how to use that and make API calls without again asking authorization from the user??

Any thoughts??

Thanks,
Aniket

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's better to use Server to Server authentication by using P12 key:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

You can impersonate a user account and all files will be accessible by your server.

```
$client_email = '1234567890-  a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('MyProject.p12');
$user_to_impersonate = 'user@example.org';

$private_key = file_get_contents($pkey); //notasecret
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
$credentials = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key,
        'notasecret',  // Default P12 password
        'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
        $user_to_impersonate
    );

 $client = new \Google_Client();
 $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
 if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
 }

 $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);

 $files = $service->files->listFiles();
 echo "count files=".count($files)."<br>";       

 foreach( $files as $item ) {
     echo "title=".$item['title']."<br>";
 }
```

This will give you all files listed in your Google Drive without any client user interaction.

Comment: I had problem with `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials`, but found file and change function to `Google_AssertionCredentials`. But now I have problem: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot call constructor in google_drive\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Drive.php on line 75`