# php server google drive download file in background

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I need form PHP level, in background without user interaction login on google drive and get files list. I found similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861295/google-drive-api-authorize-issue/31947001) and code for question working, but is required handly login, where I need login from php in background.

In [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947001/1891446) post with code for possibly login witout user interaction, but I don't know where is bug.
My code PHP:

```
<?php  
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once 'src/auth/Google_AssertionCredentials.php';


$client_email = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('key.p12');
$user_to_impersonate = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';

$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
$credentials = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key,
        'notasecret',  // Default P12 password
        'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
        $user_to_impersonate
    );

 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
 if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
 }

 $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

 $files = $service->files->listFiles();
 echo "count files=".count($files)."<br>";       

 foreach( $files as $item ) {
     echo "title=".$item['title']."<br>";
 }
 ?>
```

Vendor directory I get from [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#composer) instruction, and other files I get from this [GitHub](https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/cp2google/tree/master/google-api-php-client/src)

I had problem with function `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials`, PHP hasn't file with this function. I found that file `src/auth/Google_AssertionCredentials.php` has similar function `Google_AssertionCredentials`. I included `Google_AssertionCredentials.php` file and changed function name.

In finally I have new error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot call constructor in
>   \google_drive\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Drive.php
>   on line 75

I don't know what doing again. I tried many other metod for login on google drive, eg. load file list GET method with API_KEY, or via json file.

As result I want get file list, download them. edit and upload.

Any sugestions?

**EDIT:**

I have part sucess. I found liblary [this](http://code.vtiger.com/david.valminos/vtigercrm/tree/56e881db3ec02425deb71808a6a098ed0279e71d/libraries/google-api-php-client), and them work with this code:

```
<?php  
function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}

session_start();
require_once '/google-api-php-client/autoload.php';


$client_email = 'xxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$user_to_impersonate = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('key.p12');

$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key,
        'notasecret',  // Default P12 password
        'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
        $user_to_impersonate
    );

 $client = new Google_Client();
 if(isset($_SESSION['service_token'])==false && $_SESSION['service_token']=='') {
     $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
     if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($credentials);
     }
    $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['service_token']) && $_SESSION['service_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);

        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $_SESSION['service_token'] =  $client->getAccessToken();
        }

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
print_r(retrieveAllFiles($service));
}
 ?>
```

And in result I have only one file `[originalFilename] => Getting started`, this is PDF, but I don't see this file on Gogle dirve. On google drive I uploaded file: `README.md`.

I'm not sure, but maybe this file is on ` 'xxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com' and script not logged to 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'?

Comment: Try to check if you've implemented the [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) correctly. Do note that since the PHP client is still in beta, it may have some issues with it.

Comment: @adjuremods its been in beta for four years its stable IMO.

Comment: I tried create difrent `Service Account`byt problem still again. I found that problem in in function `$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);`, beacuse when I comment this line isn't error

Comment: When i check `echo $client->getAccessToken()`, is revicing token in json format. I think that authentication work correctly, but is problem with get drive service.

Comment: I updated question. and I tried share files for `xxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and now I can see files. Bul how 'logged' from xxx@gmail.com account?